# Use custom objects as the source for Microsoft Reports (.rdlc)

Tags: object, reporting, rdlc

In some instances, I prefer working with custom objects instead of strongly typed datasets and data rows.  However, it seems like Microsoft Reporting (included with VS2005) requires strongly typed datasets.

Is there a way to use my custom objects to design and populate reports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer.  Yes,  it's possible.  You just have to add a custom object as a datasource in visual studio.

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/objectdatasources/index.html

Comment: Can I Use custom objects as the source for Remote Reports (***RDL***), ***not RDLC*** ?

Answer (score 3):

I could never choose one of my own POCOs in Report Data setup from my project to be a model for the report - the alleged 'global' option mentioned in the [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692.aspx) was not there.  So I ended up having to edit the XML to define the type and an imitation data source (which does not actually exist in my project).

I assign the data of type `Aies.Core.Model.Invoice.MemberInvoice` to the report in code

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MemberInvoice", new[] { invoice1 }));
```

And the custom definition is:

```
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="MemberInvoice">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>3fe04def-105a-4e9b-99db-630c1f8bb2c9</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="MemberInvoice">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="MemberId">
          <DataField>MemberId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="DateOfIssue">
          <DataField>DateOfIssue</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="DateDue">
          <DataField>DateDue</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Amount">
          <DataField>Amount</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Decimal</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>MemberInvoice</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:DataSetName>Aies.Core.Model.Invoice</rd:DataSetName>
        <rd:TableName>MemberInvoiceData</rd:TableName>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod>GetInvoices</rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethodSignature>System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Aies.Core.Model.Invoice.MemberInvoice] GetInvoices()</rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethodSignature>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceType>Aies.Core.Model.Invoice.MemberInvoiceData, Aies.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</rd:ObjectDataSourceType>
      </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the XML! All the info I could find said to use the wizard, but the wizard was not giving me the options that other people had, nor did I have the "global" option as you said. I was able to copy this and modify it to fit my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set up SSRS to read data values from a more or less arbitrary object.  [This Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.dataprocessing.idatareaderfieldproperties_members(SQL.90).aspx) describes the IDataReaderFieldProperties object in the API which (IIRC) allows you to specify the getter method to invoke to get a value.