# RDLC Reports - I can only specify a database data source rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, report, rdlc, syncfusion

Problem looks like this:
I have web application and when I create new report.rdlc I can only specify a database data source rdlc report. Do you have idea why I can't create new data source from object?

Comment: Did you try to search?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038288/issues-setting-rdlc-datasource-to-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126863/use-custom-objects-as-the-source-for-microsoft-reports-rdlc/157371#157371

Answer (score 1):

1.Please refer the following documentation for using a Business Object Data Source.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

2.Also you can add using external class library,to do this follow the steps.

- Create a class library with property, methods in a class.
- Add created class library using Addreference option in the Data source configuration wizard.
- Select the added class library and follow the steps provided in the Walkthrough.

Thanks,
Anandakumar S